# Jquery: How to associate onready for divs created after page load

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have few divs which will be created by a script not in my control on the web page. These divs will be created after page has completely loaded, based on AJAX data. How can I associate onready event with these divs.

Comment: Can you show the code and how they're loaded?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is there a jQuery DOM change listener?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2844565/is-there-a-jquery-dom-change-listener)

Comment: Why not just call some function to create these divs in ajax complete?

Comment: I don't have control on Ajax complete or access to it's source code. Also, will need a solution which works on all browsers, including mobile.

Comment: No access to code of Ajax.   The div loaded will be <div> old text</div>. I will need to change it to <div> new text</div>

Comment: The best solution would be to fix *"I don't have control on Ajax complete or access to it's source code."* and improve that code so that it triggers an event you can listen for.

Comment: Some browsers offer mutation observers to catch child insertions, but if you know nothing about these divs it will be really hard to figure out when they are ready.

Comment: You most definitely can access the source code that's sending the ajax request, and with that information, you may be able to override a piece of it that would allow you to perform this action. since we (the stackoverflow community) can't see said code, we can't help you with figuring out if that's possible.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you are looking for event delegation. [jQuery's .on() method](http://api.jquery.com/on/) has a very simple approach to attaching event handlers to dynamically created elements. For example:

```
$( "#dataDiv" ).on( "click", "div", function() {
  $( this ).fadeOut();
});
```

That code will listen for click events on all current and future div elements within `#dataDiv` and then hide whatever was clicked on.

You can delegate all standard jQuery event types in this manner. Hope that helps!

Answer (score 0):

You cannot but you can use event delegation if its about clicks/hovering etc. See http://api.jquery.com/on/#direct-and-delegated-events

Comment: @JDT please post the code to jsfiddle or explain the reason why you can't access those div's from the code

Answer (score 0):

If you have no control on the scripts, what you can do is use [ajaxComplete()](http://api.jquery.com/ajaxComplete/) to check if your divs are present after each ajax request completes.